# What is OAuth2Request.getExtensions()?

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, spring-security-oauth2

In Spring Security OAuth, what is the purpose of the method `OAuth2Request::getExtensions`? Is it something that a client can populate? Or is it something that a developer can modify internally to track additional information on the user. There is [no documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/oauth/apidocs/org/springframework/security/oauth2/provider/OAuth2Request.html#getExtensions()) on this method.

It is important to know because if it is meant to be populated by clients, then we have to keep it as un-trused information. But if not, we can trust it.